# How to get values from my datframe with two values?

Tags: dataframe

I'm trying to get the values after the commas on a dataframe that has two values in each column

My dataframe looks like this.

[image]

Thanks!

P.S. *I started programming today*

Comment: Hey @thiago, Welcome to StackOverFlow :) Please remember to expect great answers only if the question is formatted well. I have made some edits to your question (will be reflected shortly). I suggest you to add further info like how was the dataframe obtained ?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [[10, 11], [12,13]], 'c2': [[100, 110], [120,130]]})
>>df
         c1          c2
0  [10, 11]  [100, 110]
1  [12, 13]  [120, 130]
>>> for index,row in df.iterrows():
...     print(row['c1'][1])
...
11
13
```

I suppose this is what you want